Are plastic pipe clamps a problem for thermal expansion of PEX?
I am installing some PEX plumbing in my basement. I like to use this type of plastic pipe clamps (with some 3/4" screws), but they really hold the pipe securely - it cannot move freely, and when 3 or more are on a line (at 24" intervals), even I cannot move the pipe.
A hot water line I've previously installed with these clamps droops significantly when hot.
Is this type of clamp OK to use, or am I asking for trouble? Maybe it's better to use the single nail plastic half clamps, since they do not seem to restrict movement as much.


What does the PEX manufacturer say to use?

Those clamps are intended for PEX, copper, and CPVC. You are good to use them.
When PEX gets hot, it becomes much more pliable, even if you used oversized clamps that did not tighten to the PEX at all, it would sag between with 24" spacings. That's just what PEX does.

I think the reason I could not move the pipe when clamped is that the pipe was not straight when installed - so it was pulling against the clamps. I tried it again with a totally straight pipe, and it moves fine.

Can you see any harm in supporting the PEX every 12"? These pipes are visible in my basement, and I would like to minimize the obvious sagging (I understand it will still sag; I'd just like smaller sections sagging).

Supporting PEX every 12" should not be an issue. The only thing to look out for is changes in direction. Say you have a long straight run that ends in a 90-degree change of direction. After the elbow, you want to keep some space before you use a clamp so that you don't put stress on the joint from thermal expansion. Refer to the manufacturer as to the minimum space, but I would think 12" or more would be adequate.
